# AutoIT Run notepad Command

Tags: autoit

What do I need to do to run a SAVED notepad file?
Current code is this:

```
Run("Notepad.exe", "C:\Users\Caleb Austing\Documents\AutoIT\Alphas\TFRO Hub Welcome Pack\TFRO Hub Update Log.txt")
```

I have also got:

```
Run("notepad.exe", @ScriptDir & "TFRO Hub Update Log.txt")
```

Which is all a part of:

```
Func StartUpdatelog()
    Run("notepad.exe", @ScriptDir & "TFRO Hub Update Log.txt")

EndFunc
```

Answer (score 3):

You put the file as the "WorkingDir" argument. That is the problem.

The file must be specified with the program in the [Run](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Run.htm)-Function.

```
Run("notepad.exe C:\Users\Caleb Austing\Documents\AutoIT\Alphas\TFRO Hub Welcome Pack\TFRO Hub Update Log.txt")
```

Or

```
Run("notepad.exe " & @ScriptDir & "\TFRO Hub Update Log.txt")
```

Or you can use [ShellExecute](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ShellExecute.htm)

```
ShellExecute("notepad.exe", @ScriptDir & "\TFRO Hub Update Log.txt")
```

Add a backslash before the file name, because the variable @ScriptDir contains the path without a terminating backslash.